# closed form in terms of a polygamma function? $ f(2,2)=\sum \sum \exp\big(- n^2k^2 \big)? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, theta-functions, polygamma

> Is there a closed form for:$$ f(2,2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \exp\big(- n^2k^2 \big)? $$

Note that I'm defining a function: $$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\exp\big(-n^xk^y\big)$$ and seeking a closed form for:

$f(2,2)\approx .404$

In the case $f(1,1)$ there is indeed a closed form in terms of something called a [q-Polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) which can sometimes be related to Jacobi theta functions.

This is interesting because $f(2)$ can be written in terms of a Jacobi third theta function.

Comment: Perhaps, we can rewrite it as $\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\tau(d) e^{-d^2}$, where $\tau(d)$ is the number of divisors of $d$ and then consider the summation indexed by primes etc. Not sure, if this help, though.